# take photo with wear OS android

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-3.0

I needed to know if I can use the camera on a watch, with the same API I use the camera on mobile?
The application I needed to do was take a photo with a wear.

I've been searching the google documentation in the wear os section and I can't find any reference to the interaction with the camera's API.

Note: this application that I aspire to make had no interaction with the smartphone.

Does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: which Wear OS device have camera built-in?

Comment: Kospet Prime 2, for example

Comment: its not Wear OS device, its usual Android (10) modified to work on such device

Comment: So, in principle, can I program it like a "normal" smartphone (android)?

Comment: theoretically yes :)

Comment: be aware that manufacturers of such devices (with "real" Android, not Wear OS) must make a lot of mods in their system version, oftenly locks some 3rd party apps/store and for your camera case: there is a possibility that "technically" from framework side there is no camera at all and only manufacturers camera app have some custom access, not via Camera2 API

Comment: yes, is my fear. thanks @snachmsm!

Comment: I could always choose a watch with wear os... but I can't find one with a camera and that explains not having an API...

Comment: let me post an "official" answer for you question :) exacly: there is no API, because Wear OS devices don't have cameras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no API, because Wear OS devices don't have cameras, not a single one... some smartwatches with cameras and "Android" system have "real" Android system adjusted to such devices by manufacturer. on those you may use common Camera2 API (if manufacturer didn't blocked cam access somehow, as this is modified OS distribution)